# How to include user interface into eclipse for google app engine java?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, dreamweaver

I had design my User Interface in dreamweaver and I hope to include the User Interface that I had design into eclipse for google app engine java, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Are you asking if you can include the Dreamwever generated HTML/CSS into your AppEngine project? Otherwise can you please tell us a little more in order for us to provide any useful feedback

Comment: Yup... I hope that I can directly use the dreamweaver generated html/css into my AppEngine project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all HTML/CSS/Javascript into the "war" or "web" directory of the App Engine project (next to the index.jsp or index.html which is probably already there). Those files will be uploaded and served as static files when deployed.

I assume that you will have to modify at least some of those files, though, to make them "active". For example by turning the HTML into JSP and wiring them up with some servlets that do the server-side processing.